# Need help creating a table from survey data

Tags: r

I feel like this is a simple problem that I should be able to figure out myself, but I just can't seem to come up with a solution.

I've been reading various posts both here and elsewhere but I can't seem to come across an example of what I want to do (maybe I'm just not using the right terminology?).

I've got some survey data structured like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(101,102,103,104,105,106,107), 
q1_1 = c(1,3,3,2,5,4,2), 
q1_2 = c(3,4,5,5,2,1,1), 
q1_3 = c(5,5,2,2,3,1,4))

df
```

I can create a table that gives me the response proportions:

```
round(prop.table(table(df$q1_1)),3)*100
```

What I want though is to build that same table, but with multiple rows (each row being a different question) and the columns being the response levels.  How do I do that?

This is driving me nuts.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```
> out <- lapply(df, function(x) round(prop.table(table(x)),3)*100)
> do.call(rbind, out[2:4])
        1    2    3    4    5
q1_1 14.3 28.6 28.6 14.3 14.3
q1_2 28.6 14.3 14.3 14.3 28.6
q1_3 14.3 28.6 14.3 14.3 28.6
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm smacking my forehead looking that solution.